# writeToFile fails - how do I debug WHY it fails (what tools)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm getting an NSDictionary from JSON (using SBJson), and I want to store it. I'm using

```
[liveData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES]
```

and it fails. The data *looks* like its all NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray (which "atomically:YES" demands). I used the same  localFilePath elesewhere.

So my question is: how can I find out where the problem is? What tools can I use to understand why writeToFile fails? The log doesn't show an error message.

Comment: Have you NSLogged your `localFilePath` to see what the value is? Are you sure you gave it a unique name to save as?

Comment: I agree the problem is likely your path, can you include that code?

Comment: I have logged my localFilePath, and I've also used it elsewhere in my code to store something else (changing only the file name -- it's NSTemporaryDirectory() plus filename) so I'm pretty sure that's not it. But really my question is: how do I debug this issue -- how can I find out more about the failure? Is there an error code or some debugging tool in xcode outside of the logger that would help me pin it down? Or do I just need to use trial and error to pinpoint it?

Answer (score 9):

It may have multiple reasons:

- The path you are writing to is wrong, not writable (you don't have write access to it), or the parent directory does not exists (if `localFilePath` is "/path/to/file.plist" but the directory "/path/to/" does not exists, it will fail)
- The liveData dictionary does contains objects that are not PropertyList objects. Only `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` objects can be written into a Property List file (and `writeToFile:atomically:` **do** write to a plist file so the dictionary **do** have to contains only PList objects for that method to succeed)

Comment: Also worth noting, if you have a `NULL` value in your dictionary `writeToFile` will fail.

Comment: Any value of class NSNull in the dictionary will fail. So, explicitly check all values before putting into the dictionary. In my case, I was reading values from JSON (server data) which is a good source of such values.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a 2 year old question.  But since I just had this same problem and fixed it here's what I found.  I bet your NSDictionary has some keys that are not NSStrings.

Instead of keying like:

```
[_myDictionay setObject:thisObj forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:keyNumber]];
```

Key like:

```
[_myDictionay setObject:thisObj forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",numberWithInt:keyNumber]];
```

That fixed my problem right up.

The top way can't be saved to a plist file.

Since you're getting your info from a JSON conversion, it is possible that there are some objects or keys that are NSNumbers in there.  You would have to convert them.  But that's a pain.

So since you already have it in json, just store it as the json string in its entirety in a @"data" key and the re-expand it when you load the plist later back into your array or dict.

Comment: This fixed my problem (in my case, I had keys that were `NSDate`s), however, it still doesn't answer the question of what tools are available to debug.  It'd be great if there was something I could poke at the code with that would say something like "*NSDate is not a valid key to write to a plist file*" or some such.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried saving an NSDictionary to disk with only numbers for keys and values.  Switching the keys to NSString works but not when they keys are NSNumber.  Do keys have to be NSString?

EDIT: I know better now that it can be any object that responds to hash; often it's NSString's, though.

Comment: Yes they do.  See my answer above.

Comment: Sigh… had to convert from NSNumber to NSString to save the data to file. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread : But this apple thread would be nice to read. Basically iOS has issue in Cache directory. For 1000+ folders it returns error.

I would suggest to add your own atomic mechanism to write file as a fallback.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128927