# NSDictionary writeToFile not writing

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I run the following code with valid dictionaries and still get "not written":

```
 NSFileManager* fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
 __autoreleasing NSError* err = nil;

 NSURL* DD = [fm URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&err];
 if (!err) {
     NSString* debugPath = [[DD path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"debug.plist"];

     NSLog(@"login-signup write that file!");
     NSDictionary* remMe = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[userJSON objectForKey:kRememberMeToken],kRememberMeToken,[userJSON objectForKey:@"id"],@"id",nil];

     NSMutableDictionary* toStore = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
     [toStore setObject:Password.text forKey:kPassword];
     NSMutableDictionary* toStoreTwo = nil;
     if([fm fileExistsAtPath:debugPath]){
           toStoreTwo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:debugPath];
           [toStoreTwo setObject:[toStore copy] forKey:@"signup"];
           [toStoreTwo setObject:remMe forKey:@"login"];
     }
     else{
           toStoreTwo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[toStore copy] forKey:@"signup"];
           [toStoreTwo setObject:remMe forKey:@"login"];
     }

     NSDictionary* sDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:toStoreTwo forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"signup-debug-%@",[NSDate date]]];

     NSLog(@"saving %@ to file",sDict);
     BOOL success = [sDict writeToFile:debugPath atomically:NO];
     if(!success){
            NSLog(@"not written");
     }
     else{
            NSLog(@"written");
     }
   }
```

any help would be great!

Stackoverflow requires more content to explain the code, but I think it's pretty easy to see what's going on, if you have any questions please comment!

Comment: Please do not store username and password credentials in a file, that is what the keychain is for.

Comment: it's for debugging something. This isn't production code.

Comment: Yes daniel, please chill, your personal info is not being stolen

Answer (score 0):

Look on this question [write to file fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519996/writetofile-fails-how-do-i-debug-why-it-fails-what-tools). I has some problem, but after check all data types in my dictionary found the wrong.